# What does the following quote on John von Neumann mean?

Tags: logic, soft-question

Wikipedia has the following quote on John von Neumann:

> Stan Ulam, who knew von Neumann well, described his mastery of
>   mathematics this way: "Most mathematicians know one method. For
>   example, Norbert Wiener had mastered Fourier transforms. Some
>   mathematicians have mastered two methods and might really impress
>   someone who knows only one of them. John von Neumann had mastered
>   three methods." He went on to explain that the three methods were:
>
> - A facility with the symbolic manipulation of linear operators;
> - An intuitive feeling for the logical structure of any new mathematical    theory;
> - An intuitive feeling for the combinatorial superstructure of    new theories.

And I am wondering what do 'logical structure' and 'combinatorial superstructure' mean in this context?
Please explain these methods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann#Mastery_of_mathematics

Comment: It seems to me that the three are not "methods" but "capabilities" : facility, intuition, ... It is hard to imagine a way to "learn" them. You can see : Giorgio Israel and Ana Millán Gasca, [The World as a Mathematical Game: John von Neumann and Twentieth Century Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=6o52lsjG83UC&printsec=frontcover) (2009) for a "book [that] provides the first comprehensive scientific and intellectual biography of John von Neumann, a man who perhaps more than any other is representative of twentieth century science."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quote is from *Adventures of a Mathematician* (by Stanislaw Ulam):

> *"Von Neumann was different. He also had several quite independent
>   techniques at his fingertips. (It is rare to have more than two or
>   three.) These included a facility for symbolic manipulation of linear
>   operators. He also had an undefinable "common sense" feeling for
>   logical structure and for both the skeleton and the combinatorial
>   superstructure in new mathematical theories. This stood him in good
>   stead much later, when he became interested in the notion of a
>   possible theory of automata, and when he undertook both the conception
>   and the construction of electronic computing machines. He attempted to
>   define and to pursue some of the formal analogies between the workings
>   of the nervous system in general and of the human brain itself." (page
>   96)*

In *The World as a Mathematical Game* (by Giorgio Israel and Ana Millán Gasca), we read that:

> *"In actual fact, during the Königsberg Congress, none of the eminent
>   participants realized the full import and implications of the result
>   announced by Gödel – with one exception: von Neumann. After the
>   discussion the latter rushed up to Gödel and took him aside in order
>   to get a better understanding of his demonstration. He then left the
>   Congress in a state of extraordinary excitement and spent the next
>   month working on the issue. Less than two months later he wrote to
>   Gödel to announce he had demonstrated, as a consequence of the theorem
>   of incompleteness, that the consistency of arithmetic cannot be
>   proved. Gödel replied that he had in the meantime succeeded in
>   obtaining this demonstration and sent him a copy of the article that
>   had already been presented for publication." (Chapter 2, page 30, ISBN 978-3-7643-9895-8 Birkhäuser Verlag AG, Basel - Boston - Berlin)*

And in [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGSs8luBt_s), Eugene Wigner tells a story where he asked Neumann if he could explain a theorem. Neumann asked Wigner whether he knows certain other theorems and a few more things. Subsequently, he provided an explanation (proof) on the spot using only theorems Wigner knew. Wigner concludes:

> *"He understood things, not only in one way, but also together/in
>   combination [with other theorems] ['összefoghatóan']."*

**The Hilbertian view of mathematics was that of a gigantic "combinatorial game", and the above quotes demonstrate Neumann's ability to see how the elements combine together in a theory (skeleton) or how the theory (or theorem) connects (fit with) other theories (combinatorial superstructure).**

---

Some further quotes from *The World as a Mathematical Game*:

> *"Moreover, his work on axiomatization and on proof theory led to a
>   view of mathematics as «a combinatorial game played using primitive
>   symbols in which it had to be determined in a finitely combinatorial
>   way which combinations of primitive symbols the methods of
>   construction or ‘proof’ led to», as he claimed at the Königsberg
>   congress (Neumann (von) 1931). He never abandoned this view, and
>   indeed built it up over the years, and this view helps to explain his
>   interest in the scientific topics he concerned himself with in the
>   1940s and 1950s." (Chapter 2, page 30)*

and

> *"Commenting on von Neumann’s scientific personality, Jean Dieudonné
>   claimed that   his genius lay in analysis and combinatorics, the
>   latter being understood in a very wide sense, including the uncommon
>   ability to organize and axiomatize complex situations that a priori do
>   not seem amenable to mathematical treatment, as in quantum mechanics
>   and the theory of games (Dieudonné 1976, 89)." (Chapter 2, page 48)*

and

> *"For von Neumann, the world must be conceived of as a mathematical
>   game, in the sense that in all cases it is useful and effective to
>   seek axiomatic structures suitable for thinking of the phenomena in
>   mathematical terms. The concept of strategic game is a kind of
>   universal key for considering in terms of combinatorial structures all
>   the interactions occurring in reality and to determine the conditions
>   in which they allow an "acceptable" solution. But this in no way means
>   that the world is actually a mathematical game. The conception of
>   social interactions as a game, the combinatorial view on which the
>   theory of automata will be founded, the analogy between brain and
>   computer are tools of epistemological analysis, never ontological
>   views." (Chapter 3.5, page 73)*